# Dialog по размеру всего экрана Android

Tags: java, android, blur, dialog

Не получается создать кастомный диалог для своего android-приложения таким образом, чтобы он занимал всю высоту (А может быть и ширину, на планшетах не проверяли) экрана.

При том, у меня на устройстве все работает как надо, т.е. диалог "блюрит" все позади себя
[image: Нормальный блюр]

На другом устройстве диалог не блюрит все позади себя по высоте. Android-версия того устройства- 5.1.1. У меня 6.0.1

[image: Фиговый блюр]

Как создаются диалоги:

```
public CustomDialog1 buildDialog(Context context){
        dialog = new Dialog(context);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_with_1_button);
        View dialogBackground = dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogBlurBackground1);
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = dialog.getWindow().getAttributes();
        lp.width = MATCH_PARENT;
        lp.height = MATCH_PARENT;
        dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
        return this;
    }
```

**dialog_with_1_button.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.github.mmin18.widget.RealtimeBlurView
        android:id="@+id/dialogBlurBackground1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:realtimeBlurRadius="10dp"
        app:realtimeOverlayColor="#00e9e9e9" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/background"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/dialog_background"
        android:elevation="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dialogTitle1"
            fontPath="fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dialogFirstText1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dialogSecondText1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/dialogButton1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/dialog_but_background_first"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:paddingRight="20dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создайте такой стиль:

```
<style name="DialogStyle" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMajor">95%</item>
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMinor">95%</item>
    <item name="windowFixedHeightMajor">95%</item>
    <item name="windowFixedHeightMinor">95%</item>
</style>
```

(minor и major - это параметры для разных ориентаций экрана. Т.е. например, при портрентой - берется `android:windowMinWidthMinor`)

Использование:

`AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity(), R.style.DialogStyle);`

Параметр с высотой не проверял, с шириной работает нормально. Единственное - на планшете вылазил белый бэк, пришлось его "обнулять":

```
<item name="android:background">@null</item>
<item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
```

Comment: Помогло, только про использовании такого стиля цвет текста становится черным, приходится задавать его программно

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вместо **setAttributes()**

```
dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
```

**setLayout()**

```
dialog.getWindow().setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
```

Comment: Нет, даже это не помогло :(